Terraform rabbitmq
I have this rabbitMQ module which runs fine when deploying (terraform apply)
locals {
  facts = var.tags
}

# cluster access definition
data "tls_certificate" "eks_oidc_thumbprint" {
  url = var.eks_cluster_data.oidc_issuer_url
}


#########################################
### Policy and role setup

# Create OIDC provider
resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "oidc_provider" {
  url = data.tls_certificate.eks_oidc_thumbprint.url
  client_id_list = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
  thumbprint_list = [data.tls_certificate.eks_oidc_thumbprint.certificates[0].sha1_fingerprint]

  tags = merge({ component = "oidc-provider" }, local.facts)
}


# IAM Policy for EBS CSI Driver
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ebs_csi_driver_policy" {
  name        = "AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_Driver_Policy_${local.facts.env}"
  description = "Policy for EKS EBS CSI Driver"
  policy      = file("${path.module}/ebs_csi/ebs-csi-policy.json")  

  tags = merge({ component = "ebs-csi-driver-policy" }, local.facts)
}

# IAM Role for EBS CSI Driver
resource "aws_iam_role" "ebs_csi_driver_role" {
    name                = "AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole_${local.facts.env}"
    assume_role_policy  = jsonencode({
        Version = "2012-10-17"
        Statement = [
         {
            Effect = "Allow"
            Principal = {
                Federated = aws_iam_openid_connect_provider.oidc_provider.arn
            }
            Action = "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
            Condition = {
                StringEquals = {
                    "${replace(data.tls_certificate.eks_oidc_thumbprint.url, "https://", "")}:sub" = "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-${local.facts.env}-controller-sa"
                }
            }
         }
        ]
    })

    tags = merge({ component = "ebs-csi-driver-role" }, local.facts)
}

# Attach Policy to Role
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_ebs_csi_driver_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ebs_csi_driver_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ebs_csi_driver_policy.arn
}
# Kubernetes Service Account for EBS CSI Driver with IAM Role annotation
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "ebs_csi_controller_sa" {
  metadata {
    name      = "ebs-csi-${local.facts.env}-controller-sa"
    namespace = "kube-system"
    annotations = {
      "eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn" = aws_iam_role.ebs_csi_driver_role.arn
    }
    labels = merge(local.facts, {
      component = "ebs-csi-controller-sa"
    })
  }
}



#########################################
### RabbitMQ Volumes prep

# Define AWS EBS Volumes
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "rabbitmq" {
  count             = length(var.azs)
  availability_zone = element(var.azs, count.index)
  size              = 8
  type              = "gp2"

  tags = merge(local.facts, {
    component = "rabbitmq-ebs",
    volume_id = "volume-${count.index}"
  })
}

# Define Kubernetes Storage Class
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "rabbitmq" {
  count = length(var.azs)

  metadata {
    name = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-storage-class-${count.index}"
    labels = merge(local.facts, {
      component = "rabbitmq-storage-class"
    })
  }

  storage_provisioner = "ebs.csi.aws.com"

  parameters = {
    type = "gp2"
  }
}

# Define Kubernetes Persistent Volumes
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "rabbitmq" {
  count = length(var.azs)

  metadata {
    name = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-pv-${count.index}"
    labels = merge(local.facts, {
      component = "rabbitmq-persistent-volume"
    })
  }

  spec {
    capacity = {
      storage = "8Gi"
    }

    access_modes = ["ReadWriteOnce"]

    persistent_volume_reclaim_policy = "Delete"

    storage_class_name = kubernetes_storage_class.rabbitmq[count.index].metadata[0].name

    persistent_volume_source {
      aws_elastic_block_store {
        volume_id = aws_ebs_volume.rabbitmq[count.index].id
        fs_type   = "ext4"
      }
    }
  }

  # Ensure Helm release for EBS CSI driver is destroyed after PV
  # depends_on = [
  #   aws_ebs_volume.rabbitmq,
  #   # kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim.rabbitmq,
  # ]
}

# Define Kubernetes Persistent Volume Claims
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "rabbitmq" {
  count = length(var.azs)

  metadata {
    name      = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-pvc-${count.index}"
    namespace = "infra"
    labels = merge(local.facts, {
      component = "rabbitmq-persistent-volume-claim"
    })
  }

  spec {
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteOnce"]

    resources {
      requests = {
        storage = "8Gi"
      }
    }

    storage_class_name = kubernetes_storage_class.rabbitmq[count.index].metadata[0].name
  }

  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_persistent_volume.rabbitmq,
  ]
}


#########################################
### Enable AWS EBS CSI driver
resource "helm_release" "aws_ebs_csi_driver" {
  name       = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  chart      = "aws-ebs-csi-driver"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  version    = "2.20.0"  

  set {
    name  = "controller.replicas"
    value = "2"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.serviceAccount.create"
    value = "false" # use existing service account
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.serviceAccount.name"
    value = "ebs-csi-${local.facts.env}-controller-sa"
  }

  set {
    name  = "node.serviceAccount.create"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "node.serviceAccount.name"
    value = "ebs-csi-node-sa"
  }

  set {
    name  = "region"
    value = var.aws_region
  }

  set {
    name  = "enableVolumeScheduling"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "enableVolumeResizing"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "enableVolumeSnapshot"
    value = "true"
  }

  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_persistent_volume.rabbitmq, 
    kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim.rabbitmq,
  ]

}

#########################################
### Prepare Queues
resource "kubernetes_secret" "load-definition" {
  metadata {
    name      = "load-definition"
    namespace = "infra"
    labels = merge(local.facts, {
      component = "rabbitmq-load-definition"
    })
  }

  data = {
    "load_definitions.json" = file("${path.module}/rabbit_queues/definitions.json")
  }

}


#########################################
### Deploy RabbitMQ
resource "helm_release" "rabbitmq" {
  name             = "rabbit-rabbitmq"
  repository       = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart            = "rabbitmq"
  namespace        = "infra"
  create_namespace = true
  version          = "14.4.0"

  set {
    name  = "auth.username"
    value = "fbmquser"
  }
  set_sensitive {
    name  = "auth.password"
    value = var.rabbitmq_password
  }
  set_sensitive {
    name  = "auth.erlangCookie"
    value = var.rabbitmq_erlang_cookie
  }
  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "ClusterIP"
  }
  set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = "1"
  }
  set {
    name  = "persistence.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name = "persistence.existingClaim"
    value = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-pvc-1" # this is to simplify the setup ... might be needed to deploy multiple replicas to all AZs
  }
  set {
    name  = "persistence.storageClass"
    value = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-storage-class-1" # this is to simplify the setup ... might be needed to deploy multiple replicas to all AZs
  }
  
  # Set extra configuration for default vhost and permissions
  set {
    name  = "extraConfiguration"
    value = <<EOF
            default_vhost = /
            default_permissions.configure = .*
            default_permissions.read = .*
            default_permissions.write = .*
            EOF
  }

  # load definitions / create queues
    set {
    name  = "loadDefinition.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }
  set {
    name  = "loadDefinition.existingSecret"
    value = "load-definition"
  }
  set {
    name  = "loadDefinition.file"
    value = "/app/load_definitions.json"
  }

  # Set graceful termination period for RabbitMQ pods
  set {
    name  = "terminationGracePeriodSeconds"
    value = "60"
  }
  
  depends_on = [
     kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim.rabbitmq
  ]
}

but when I destroy the the module .. it gets blocked on the pvc-1, pv-1 and volume (unable to detach) ...
The problem is, that I am creating two for each availability zone I have ... but only one volume gets attached...
thus the
  set {
    name = "persistence.existingClaim"
    value = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-pvc-1" # this is to simplify the setup ... might be needed to deploy multiple replicas to all AZs
  }
  set {
    name  = "persistence.storageClass"
    value = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-storage-class-1" # this is to simplify the setup ... might be needed to deploy multiple replicas to all AZs
  }

I tried to rewrite the module so it uses only one.. but then it mismatches the availability zone with it's EC (EC vs EBS - their availibility zone does not match) ... and hardcoding it doesn't sound like a good idea ...
The best solution would be to replicate in all AZs ... but I am not sure how ...
I tried
 set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = length(var.azs)
  }
  set {
    name  = "persistence.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }

 dynamic "set" {
   for_each = var.azs
   content {
        name = "persistence.existingClaim[${count.index}]"
    value = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-pvc-${count.index}" 
  
   }
 }

 dynamic "set" {
   for_each = var.azs
   content {
        name = "persistence.storageClass[${count.index}]"
    value = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-storage-class-${count.index}" 
  
   }
 }
  

But that didn't work either :(
Any idea what am I missing? Thx a lot


when I destroy the the module .. it gets blocked on the pvc-1, pv-1 and volume (unable to detach)

This is because the volumes are still in used. You can specify the dependency of these resources using depends_on; so that when you perform terraform destroy; the volumes will only destroy after the rabbitmq is uninstalled thus detached the volumes.
resource "helm_release" "rabbitmq" {
  name             = "rabbit-rabbitmq"
  ...
  depends_on = [kubernetes_persistent_volume.rabbitmq]
}


that didn't help :( it's still the same ... I guess the main problem is that the pvc-1 and pv1 (thus one of the volumes) are not binded properly .. due to the  value = "rabbitmq-${local.facts.env}-pvc-1" # this is to simplify the setup ... might be needed to deploy multiple replicas to all AZs ...  I am suspicious that if I manage to bind them both .. it would resolve it .. yet again - I am not sure how

If not bind correctly, your rabbitmq won't be running. Is the rabbitmq running correctly with the volume you provisioned? From your question, you have not mentioned any issue with the rabbitmq.

I am yet to test it ... however, it starts ok, I can login to the Admin UI and I don't see any warnings .. whether it processes messages correctly -> I am yet to test that

Does it used the volumes that the terraform provisioned? Note because the volumes are pre-provisioned thus AZ bounded, you need to ensure there is worker node in the same AZ as the volumes, too. If the rabbitmq already using the volumes that means you do not have AZ issue.

ok it's resolved by removing the manual configuration of PV, PVC, EBS volume, etc.. and done automatically via helm configuration .. anyway credits go to you :) thx
